# How to remove "Server" header from the restlet/jetty response?

Tags: restlet, jetty-9

I use Restlet integration with Jetty in my project. I would need to remove the "Server" header from the response as it discloses server information. But since I use Restlet integration with Jetty (restlet, jetty, org.restlet.ext.jetty.jar) the HttpConfiguration object is instantiated inside Restlet and not in my code. So I am not able to set "_sendServerVersion" as false and hence not able to remove the server header from the response. How to remove the server header from the response in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a Filter and remove the header through the Filter:

```
public class ServerFilter extends Filter {

    public ServerFilter(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterHandle(Request request, Response response) {
        response.getHeaders().set("Server", null);
        super.afterHandle(request, response);
    }

}
```

Then use it like:

```
ServerFilter serverFilter = new ServerFilter(getContext());
serverFilter.setNext(router);
return serverFilter;
```

See: https://javadocs.restlet.talend.com/2.4/jee/api/index.html for documentation